# Webpack format css selectors in weird string

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I use webpack 3 for my build process.

webpack.config.js:

```js
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: "css-loader"
    })
},

{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: [
            {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                    minimize: true,
                    modules: true,
                    importLoaders: 1
                }
            },
            {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: {
                    path: './postcss.config.js'
                }
            },
            {
                loader: "sass-loader",
                options: {
                    includePaths: [dirAssets]
                }
            }
        ],

        fallback: "style-loader",
        publicPath: './'
    })
},
```

I require my main.scss in main.js and in dev and build env my selectors looks like this:

```
._1RIaajDV8RXjVfAFhmcSaz {}
```

It should looks like:

```
.h1 {}
```

Any Idea? I can't solve this problem.

Comment: `modules:  true` is replacing all your classes with a `localIdentName` (hash:base64), set it to false or modify the generated local ident name, check my answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Weird string

> Webpack format css selectors in weird string

The `weird` string is actually a unique generated ident (hash:base64) for local scoped css.

If you don't need to use [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) in your project, just remove or set `modules: false` to solve your problem.

### [Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

> The query parameter modules enables the CSS Modules spec.
>   This enables local scoped CSS by default.

The loader replaces local selectors with unique identifiers.

```
:local(.className) { background: red; }
:local .className { color: green; }
```

The choosen unique identifiers are exported by the module.

```
._23_aKvs-b8bW2Vg3fwHozO { background: red; }
._23_aKvs-b8bW2Vg3fwHozO { color: green; }
```

### Local ident name

> You can configure the generated ident with the localIdentName query parameter (default [hash:base64])

```
{
     loader: 'css-loader',
     options: {
       modules: true,
       localIdentName: '[name]--[hash:base64:5]'
     }
}
```

#### Main.scss

```
.h1 {}
```

#### Exported css

```
.h1--_1RIaajDV8RXjVfAFhmcSaz {}
```

Comment: Works. Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly as there are other factors that will play into this but I would suspect it's your minimizing tool.

Using "minimize : true" means that you want the css-loader to squash your css files down to as small of text as it can get.  However, per the documentation sometimes this can be destructive to the css:

> minimize
>
> By default the css-loader minimizes the css if specified by the module system.
>
> In some cases the minification is destructive to the css, so you can provide your own options to the cssnano-based minifier if needed. See cssnano's documentation for more information on the available options.
>
> You can also disable or enforce minification with the minimize query parameter.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

Try turning off minification and/or introducing the cssnano as specified in the documentation.

Comment: I agree but `minimize: true` isn't related to the problem, see: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules